# PHPMailer - Problem with smtp OPEN SSL encrypt

Tags: php

I have a problem with the script sending the form request from the website. I was looking for a solution, unfortunately none works

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version in /home/autotran/domains/autotran.linuxpl.info/public_html/library/phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 270
SMTP connect() failed.

Line 270

````
     * Initiate a TLS (encrypted) session.
     * @access public
     * @return bool
     */
    public function startTLS()
    {
        if (!$this->sendCommand('STARTTLS', 'STARTTLS', 220)) {
            return false;
        }
        // Begin encrypted connection
        if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto(
            $this->smtp_conn,
            true,
            STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
        )) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }```
````

Comment: What's the framework you're using?

Comment: The web server where you application are running is configured correctly to send emails?